# Use Scala to unit test Java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, scala

I'm familiar with using mock objects to help unit test my Java types, but find the inflexibility can lead to verbose and cumbersome test types and a lot of repetition.

I've looked at using Groovy for unit tests with moderate success. I'm interested in learning Scala for itself, but would also like some advice on using it for testing Java. 
Does anyone have any advice or references on using Scala to do this?

Update to clarify what I'm after:

I've seen that there exists tools for unit testing in Scala, like [ScalaTest](http://www.artima.com/scalatest/). and [ScalaCheck](http://code.google.com/p/scalacheck/), but they focus on how to do the mechanics of testing. I'm looking for some best-practices and/or hints and tips for how unit testing should be approached with Scala. For example an equivalent of the [Javaworld JUnit best practices article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1221-junit.html?page=1) or a list of [anti-patterns](http://www.exubero.com/junit/antipatterns.html) to point out common pitfalls or useful conventions.

Comment: I'm afraid if you phrase it that vaguely, what Daniel wrote is the best you will get.

Comment: How would you suggest I rephrase it? To me "Does anyone have any advice or references on using Scala to do this?" is pretty clear

Answer (score 8):

You can certainly use Scala to test Java. In fact, since the Scala testing frameworks integrate well with JUnit, you can write the tests in Scala, and run them from Eclipse through JUnit.

There are three important frameworks: ScalaTest, general, very flexible; ScalaCheck, based on a Haskell testing framework, it generate random data to test conditions for you; Specs, general, similar in scope to ScalaTest, but has a more BDD-oriented syntax.

Comment: I know it is possible, I was looking for some guidance on doing so, sorry if that wasn't clear from my question.

Comment: I highly recommend using IntelliJ to java & scala mix development. I recently started writing units tests with scala (http://www.persistentpanda.com/2011/03/unit-testing-with-scala.html) and the only things I got from Eclipse was a headache.

Answer (score 3):

This presentation has some hints on using Scala for testing Java code: [sneaking Scala into your organization](http://days2010.scala-lang.org/node/138/169).

Answer (score 0):

Note that compilation can be fairly slow though. In noticed that while I'm programming Java, I hit the short cut keys for running the tests quite a bit more often than when I'm programming in Scala. In fact, in Scala, you definitely want to have something such as SBT sitting in the background, testing your code continuously. That means that - if all you care for is having tests written in Scala - you might need to pull in quite a bit more in order to make it into something comfortable.